# How to update ng-repeat values in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular js, I have an array I am looping it through `ng-repeat` directive, and I have written code for copy, remove, and edit values in the array.

If I want to remove or copy I can do it, done?
But if I click on edit one popup box will appear there I want to edit the values those updated values should update in the array.

How can I get it done?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Angular app</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .listv{
     margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .editpopup{
     width: 250px;
     height: 250px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     right: 0px;

     background-color:gray;
  }
  .editpopup-true{
     display: block;
  }
  .editpopup-false{
     display: none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
 <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCon">
     <div ng-repeat="s in items" class="listv">
        <span>{{s.id}}</span>
        <span>{{s.pname}}</span>
        <button ng-click="removeStudent($index)">remove</button>
        <button ng-click="copyrow($index)">copy</button>
        <button ng-click="editrow($index)">edit</button>
     </div></br>

     <div class="editpopup editpopup-{{istrue}} ">
        <p>edit id:<input type="text" ng-model="editedid"></p>
        <p>edit pname:<input type="text" ng-model="editedname"></p>
        <button ng-click="save($index)">save</button>
        <button ng-click="closepopup()">cancel</button>
     </div>

  </div>
```

```
      var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
      myApp.controller('myCon',function($scope){
      $scope.items=[{id:1,pname:'box1'},{id:2,pname:'box2'}, {id:3,pname:'box3'}];

    $scope.removeStudent=function($index){
      $scope.items.splice($index,1);
    }
  $scope.copyrow=function($index){

     $scope.len=$scope.items.length;
     $scope.ids=$scope.items[$index].id;
     $scope.pnames=$scope.items[$index].pname

     $scope.items.push({
          id:$scope.len+1,
          pname:$scope.pnames 
      });
  }
  $scope.editrow=function($index){
     $scope.istrue=true;
     $scope.editedid=$scope.items[$index].id;
     $scope.editedname=$scope.items[$index].pname;
  }
  $scope.closepopup=function(){
     $scope.istrue=false;

  }
  $scope.save=function($index){
     $scope.istrue=false;
     $scope.s.name=$scope.editedname;
  }
 });
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgpL5tk7/6/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to create a clone of the object when edit is clicked and then when save is clicked copy the data to the item in the array.

First initilize `$scope.editedItem`

```
$scope.editedItem = {};
```

For `editrow` we store the currently edited index in $index and then clone the data into `$scope.editedItem`.

```
$scope.editrow = function($index){
    $scope.istrue = true;
    $scope.$index = $index;
    angular.copy($scope.items[$index], $scope.editedItem);
}
```

Then in `save` we clone the data back into the object in the array:

```
$scope.save = function(){
    $scope.istrue = false;
    angular.copy($scope.editedItem, $scope.items[$scope.$index]) 
}
```

The view needs to be updated to instead use `editedItem`:

```
<div class="editpopup editpopup-{{istrue}} ">
    <p>edit id:<input type="text" ng-model="editedItem.id"></p>
    <p>edit pname:<input type="text" ng-model="editedItem.pname"></p>
    <button ng-click="save()">save</button>
    <button ng-click="closepopup()">cancel</button>
 </div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p03o7rab/)

Comment: It worked well for me, Is there any other possible way? Or maybe in Angular2?  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. here was my fix

My original code that didn't update the object

```
<div class="info" ng-repeat="email in vm.contactData.emails.other">
      <input type="text" ng-model="email" />
</div>
```

Used the items $index to properly bind it

```
<div class="info" ng-repeat="email in vm.contactData.emails.other">
      <input type="text" ng-model="vm.contactData.emails.other[$index]" />
</div>
```

This binding creates a re-draw issue because it doesn't know if the updated item in the array is referencing the same item that was in that spot before. To fix this i had to make a slight change to formatting of the array.

```
['email1@google.com','email2@google.com']
```

becomes

```
[
   {'email': 'email1@google.com'},
   {'email': 'email2@google.com'}
]
```

and

```
<div class="info" ng-repeat="email in vm.contactData.emails.other">
     <input type="text" ng-model="vm.contactData.emails.other[$index]" />
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="info" ng-repeat="email in vm.contactData.emails.other">
      <input type="text" ng-model="vm.contactData.emails.other[$index].email" />
</div>
```

after these changes you should have a proper bind without any re-draw issues where the input field loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

First, save the old value like this:

```
$scope.editrow=function($index){
    $scope.istrue=true;
    $scope.oldValue = $scope.items[$index].id; // save the old id
    $scope.editedid=$scope.items[$index].id;
    $scope.editedname=$scope.items[$index].pname;
};
```

Then, when you save, just find the right object with the help of the old value and assign new values like this:

```
$scope.save=function($index){
    $scope.istrue=false;
    $scope.items.forEach(function (item) {
       if(item.id == $scope.oldValue){
           item.id = $scope.editedid;
           item.pname = $scope.editedname;
       }
    });
};
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgpL5tk7/10/)

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable `$scope.getIndex=0;` and get the index from items array when you click save button. Then assign `$index` to that variable.

Now you can get `items[$scope.getIndex]` anywhere in controller. And help you to update items array:

```
$scope.getIndex=0;
$scope.editrow=function($index){
     $scope.getIndex=$index;
     $scope.istrue=true;
     $scope.editedid=$scope.items[$index].id;
     $scope.editedname=$scope.items[$index].pname;
}

$scope.save=function($index){
    $scope.istrue=false;
    $scope.items[$scope.getIndex].id=$scope.editedid;
    $scope.items[$scope.getIndex].pname=$scope.editedname;
}[enter link description here][1]
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ElavarasanS/rgpL5tk7/26/)**